# The field is unregistered when sync error triggered

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

I have a change password form, in the following structure

```
<Field name={FORM_FIELDS.OLD_PASSWORD} component={FInputField} type="password" 
validate={[Validation.required]} />
<Field name={FORM_FIELDS.NEW_PASSWORD} component={FInputField} type="password" 
validate={[Validation.required]} />
<Field name={FORM_FIELDS.CONFIRM_PASSWORD} component={FInputField} 
type="password" validate={[ Validation.shouldMatch(password)]} />
```

and the shouldMatch function

```
export const shouldMatch = (matchValue) => {
return (value) => {
    return value !== matchValue ? t('common/validationNotMatch') : undefined
}
};
```

When i input a mismatch in the CONFIRM_PASSWORD field, i got the following actions which is right

```
{ type: '@@redux-form/UPDATE_SYNC_ERRORS', meta: { form: 'changePassword' }, 
 payload: { syncErrors: { confirmPassword: 'common/validationNotMatch' } } }
```

but after this action, an UNREGISTER_FIELD action occur, which make the form to clear the sync error object

```
{ type: '@@redux-form/UNREGISTER_FIELD', meta: { form: 'changePassword' }, 
 payload: { name: 'confirmPassword', destroyOnUnmount: true } }
```

then the field is registered again

```
{ type: '@@redux-form/REGISTER_FIELD', meta: { form: 'changePassword' }, 
 payload: { name: 'confirmPassword', type: 'Field' } }
```

any help, why the UNREGISTER_FIELD action occur here? and how could i make the validation message appear always when there's a mismatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the [docs for the `Field` prop `validate`](https://redux-form.com/7.0.4/docs/api/field.md/#-code-validate-value-allvalues-props-name-gt-error-code-optional-) they mention that

> Note: if the validate prop changes the field will be re-registered.

I'm thinking that could be the underlying issue. It's not clear from the code you've posted where the `password` variable in the line `Validation.shouldMatch(password)` comes from. But for the function to make sense I guess that line will generate a new function each time the `password` changes. (Ie. the validate prop will change).

But, also from the docs, I read that the signature for the `validate` prop. is

> (value, allValues, props, name) => error [optional]

So it seems you should be  able to get the `password` value from `allValues` instead, and then you could maybe avoid changing the `validate` prop. Something like:

```js
export const shouldMatch =  (repeatedPassword, allValues) => {
  const newPassword = allValues[FORM_FIELDS.NEW_PASSWORD];
  return repeatedPassword !== newPassword ? 
     t('common/validationNotMatch') : 
     undefined
};
```

And use it like

```js
<Field 
 name={FORM_FIELDS.CONFIRM_PASSWORD} 
 component={FInputField} 
 type="password" 
 validate={[ Validation.shouldMatch ]} 
/>
```